# AKS not able to handle more requests when increasing pod count

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, azure-aks

I am running a flask server in AKS. When I manually scale there to be 1 pod, the cluster is able to handle 7 requests successfully.
When I increase the amount of pods to 2 pods, I try to send 12 requests, but still only 7 are handled successfully.
I ran the container in dockerDesktop and succsesfully handled 36 requests that were sent at the same time. On dockerdesktop the 36 simultaneous requests put "memory usage" to about 850 MB, and in AKS one pod is set to request 1000 Mb from the node (which it seems to do successfully because all pods are running).

My feeling is that the requests are not distributed between the different pods properly. Though that confuses me as well because when I run "watch -n 1 kubectl top pods" I do see a change in all the pod's used resources.

(additional question: I cannot find where to see the print() statements from my python program on Azure)

Deployment.yaml:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: jenspyl/bp-ga:latest
        env:
        - name: JWT_SECRET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: jwt-secret
              key: JWT_SECRET_KEY
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "1000Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "1000Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5003

      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: newsecrettwo
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-app
  ports:
  - port: 5003
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5003
  type: LoadBalancer
```

dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app
COPY Calculation/conda.yaml .
RUN conda update -n base conda && \
    conda env create -f conda.yaml --force
COPY Calculation /app/Calculation
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "envi", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
EXPOSE 5003
CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "envi", "python", "/app/Calculation/app.py"]
```